# How to display other language's words dynamically in textview

Tags: java, android

My project includes user given **strings to translate in various languages**.

For translations i am using the following code:

```
Translator translate = Translator.getInstance(); 
String text = translate.translate("I am programmer", Language.ENGLISH, Language.PORTUGUESE);
```

But as I set the text(translated) in a `textView` it shows empty.

How do i show the translated string in different language in the `TextView`?

Edit: after researching i found the imported library was not working somehow and translate() method was producing no string at all. So I had to change the translation process completely.

Comment: What is Translator? It isn't part of the Android API. How are you setting the text on the TextView and when are you setting it? Can you provide us with a code sample?

Comment: It's very unlikely that if all you are doing is setting a string into a text view that it's not working. 1) Try setting a static string into the text view and ensure that shows okay (`textView.setText("Hello, world.")`). 2) Ensure that the string you expect is returned from the `translate()` method (log it, for example).

Comment: @Jeffrey the static string is showing ok in English. But translated text isn't showing. Do I need to import any other library to show other language in textviews. I can't use locale cos I have dynamic translated strings not from string resources.

Comment: @Murph Translator is from a third party library which I imported into my project.

Comment: @DeepeshPaul Can you provide a whole snippet of the chunk of code you are working with. I'm assuming this is in your onCreate because if your are using that third party correctly, then both of the above lines are valid code.

Comment: Did you verify that the translated string is not empty? Printed it in a log statement? No there's nothing special you need to do to print out a localized string.